# Can I use puppeteer inside chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

I want to build a chrome extension for personal use.
The extension will scrape some webpages and it will render some information.
So I think puppeteer can help me with that.
I understand that I need to run node inside a chrome extension.
Is it possible?
I have found some answers but they are old.

Comment: No, extensions can't do that. Extensions can use standard API like XHR/fetch/DOMParser to scrape the web. There might be some existing libraries for that. If you really want node/Puppetteer you can write a separate app and invoke it from your extension via [nativeMesaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: I need to scrape some lazyloaded pages, so simple XHR fetch will not work.

Comment: You can use a content script with `"all_frames": true` and iframe in your background script (and override X-Frame-Options with webRequest) or an inactive tab (or a new minimized browser window). I think I've seen answers that explain all this in detail.

Comment: Related: [How to run Puppeteer code in any web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647694/how-to-run-puppeteer-code-in-any-web-browser)

Answer (score 12):

I know this is 9 months late but I had the same use case at work on Window machines but you can make it work with Mac.

The trick is to use puppeteer-web
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/tree/master/utils/browser#bundling-for-web-browsers

Bundle the repository and place it in your chrome extension folder and then reference it in your `popup.html` with something like

`<script src="./puppeteer/utils/browser/puppeteer-web.js"></script>`

You'll then need to take advantage of Chrome's remote debugging functionality as puppeteer-web can't start its own instance via `puppeteer.launch()` and can only use `puppeteer.connect()` to connect to an already existing chrome instance.

On windows add `--remote-debugging-port=9222` to the end of the target field of the chrome short cut as per [How to make Chrome always launch with remote-debugging-port flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51563287/how-to-make-chrome-always-launch-with-remote-debugging-port-flag)

Or on Mac `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --user-data-dir=$(mktemp -d -t 'chrome-remote_data_dir')`

Once remote debugging is activated you'll be able to see the `webSocketDebuggerUrl` property by visiting `http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version` on your browser. This is the `browserWSEndpoint` the connect method will invoke.

You will also need to add the port address to the `permissions` array in the `manifest.json` file otherwise ajax requests won't work in the chrome extension.

Eg:

`"permissions": [ "tabs" , "identity", "http://127.0.0.1:9222/*"],`

Example `popup.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example popup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button id='puppeteer-button'>Do Puppeteer Things</button>
      <script src="./puppeteer/utils/browser/puppeteer-web.js"></script>
      <script type="module" src="popup.js"></script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Example `popup.js` file

```
let browserWSEndpoint = '';
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function initiatePuppeteer() {
  await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(data) {
        browserWSEndpoint = data.webSocketDebuggerUrl;
      })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}

initiatePuppeteer();

// Assign button to puppeteer function

document
  .getElementById("puppeteer-button")
  .addEventListener("click", doPuppeteerThings);

async function doPuppeteerThings() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
    browserWSEndpoint: browserWSEndpoint
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Your puppeteer code goes here

}
```

Hope that helps, I haven't had any issues by appending remote debugging to my target field on my work window machines, despite feeling a bit hacky. I wrote a short blog post on it with better syntax highlighting [here.](https://dev.to/tchan/web-automation-using-puppeteer-inside-a-chrome-extension-318o)

Comment: Can this be shared on Chrome websotore and used without enabling the remote debugging?

Comment: This has a race condition: if the user clicks `#puppeteer-button` before the `fetch` resolves `browserWSEndpoint` will be an empty string. Best to use a promise instead of `browserWSEndpoint = data.webSocketDebuggerUrl;` so the button can `await` the correct `browserWSEndpoint` value. Also, the top link is dead.

Comment: I needed to add `-- "%1"` in target so it looks like this:
`--remote-debugging-port=9222 -- "%1"`

Comment: Seems like puppeteer-web isnt supported anymore, is there a new way of implementing this?

Answer (score 8):

Actually it is possible but with some limitations. Puppeteer use *devtools-protocol* (https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) which is available inside chrome extension when you enable deubgger in your extension manifest https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger. But inside extension is available only latest, stable version of protocol (for now is 1.3 https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-3).

But in my opinion you don't need *devtools-protocol* to handle your problem. Just use standard extension API https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index to open any URL you need (*chrome.tabs.update*), parse page inside content.js and do with that data whatever you want.