# Run puppeteer inside a chrome mv3 extension

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to make a chrome mv3 extension that will do some automations on a web page.
I want to use puppeteer and I see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55184255/can-i-use-puppeteer-inside-chrome-extension) about including in a chrome extension, but at the moment the puppeteer-web project seems discontinued.

Is possible to run puppeteer inside a chrome mv3 extension?

Comment: You should create your Chrome extension, a backend application that uses puppeteer to do whatever you wanna do and some sort of API that enables the communication between the two of them.

Comment: Extensions can automate the sites using `chrome` API of the extensions.

Comment: @wOxxOm I want to check the anchor tags inside a page to check if links are working correctly. Sometimes I had the problem that a streaming website or a site have broken links and this is very annoying. This is why puppeteer. Is there a `chrome`  api to check links in a page?

Comment: @Jason I've read that I need to have an express app and some endpoints to achive this, but while I was reading some documentations, I've discovered that maybe `puppeteer-core` can run inside a chrome extension?

Comment: See [content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/).