# Enable remote debugging on Chrome by default on mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, vscode-debugger, chrome-debugging

I am working on getting the VS Code debugger to attach to Chrome as part of my regular workflow.

I keep Chrome running all the time, and the highly-regarded VS Code Live Server extension opens my project in a new tab, which I like. I would like to be able to attach the VS Code debugger to this instance, but it looks like I have to start Chrome from the command line with

```
sudo /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Several questions:

1. Is there a way to modify Chrome's configuration file so that it always starts with that flag set?
2. Is that a stupid thing to do?
3. Do I really need the `sudo` in the line above? Some sources do not have it.
4. Alternatively, is there a way to create a desktop/toolbar shortcut to chrome that will start it will remote debugging enabled?

Thanks!

PS I see the related [SO question for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51563287/how-to-make-chrome-always-launch-with-remote-debugging-port-flag).

Comment: I've seen an answer for Mac. There was an app that allows customizing the command line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are various Mac answers that used to work that don't anymore. I found one that does and built a double-clickable icon. [I posted it on GitHub](https://github.com/natkuhn/Chrome-debug/).

Apparently it's also pretty easy to do using Automator.

Comment: I made it much easier to use the solution I posted on GitHub. There is now a .dmg that you can download; it has a double-clickable Chrome icon with "9222" superimposed, so that you can tell it from the actual Chrome.

Comment: How can anyone knew that clicking in Application Info's Icon and hitting Cmd+V you can replace the icon?
Thanks for the tip

Comment: @NatKuhn "dmg" nice but dangerous

Comment: @BGBRUNO Can you explain why it's dangerous? Thanks!

Comment: @NatKuhn nobody knows what is in compiled version