# Automation on current tab with WWW::Mechanize::Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, perl, automation

I am trying to use [WWW::Mechanize::Chrome](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Chrome) to fill in fields in the *currently active* tab in Chrome. The general goal is to automate some of the typing involved in making bank transfers so opening a new session and navigation to pages are no-go.

This is where I am at - to test a minimal level of control on the current tab:

```
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);
use WWW::Mechanize::Chrome;
 
Log::Log4perl->easy_init($ERROR);

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Chrome->new(
                       launch_exe => '/usr/bin/google-chrome',
                       launch_arg => [ "--remote-debugging-port=9223" ],
                       autoclose => 0,
                       port => 9223,
                       tab => 'current',
                      );

$mech->get('https://www.reddit.com/r/perl');
$mech->eval_in_page('alert("Hello Chrome")');

my $png = $mech->content_as_png();
```

with Chrome started like this:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9223
```

However what this actually does (on the browser side) is:

- open a new tab
- no navigation to reddit
- no alert

and on the command line it outputs this:

```
Can't connect without knowing the port?! 0 at ~/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.2/lib/site_perl/5.30.2/Chrome/DevToolsProtocol.pm line 317.
```

If Chromium is **not** running, the code works well (opens Chromium, navigates to reddit, alerts).

The docs say "Setting tab to `current` will use the current, active tab instead - but it does not seem to work.

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When I test this script,  the constructor `WWW::Mechanize::Chrome->new( ...)` aborts with error *"Can't connect without knowing the port?! 0 at /home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/lib/site_perl/5.30.0/Chrome/DevToolsProtocol.pm line 317."*

Comment: @HåkonHægland - correct, I added that to the question, and specified that my info referred to what happens in the browser

Comment: Added [bug report](https://github.com/Corion/WWW-Mechanize-Chrome/issues/56)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick chat with the author of WWW::Mechanize::Chrome off-band. He says you need to set the remote debugging port when you launch the Chrome instance you want to attach to. It does this automatically when it opens a new one.

```
--remote-debugging-port 9222
```

[Here is some information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51563287/1331451) about turning it on all the time.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to work. I've updated the question accordingly. Appreciate the insider knowledge though